# How to apply Overlay on the newly inserted DIV

Tags: jquery, hover

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jfSGW/1/) fiddle..
When I try to Insert a DIV on hover the below content is moved down to give the space for newly inserted DIV. And why the newly inserted DIV is removed when I hover off from the #a DIV.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you need. The movement of the content below is perfectly normal. You are adding some element which takes its own space, hence the rest of the elements move down. The div being removed is also because of the second function in your hover event, which removes the #New div on mouseout. What are you exactly trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position: absolute` as in http://jsfiddle.net/jfSGW/6/

That `div` is correctly removed because you dictated it in the second parameter to `$.hover()`

If you want popup div to be ultimately removed, but stick around while you hover over it, you can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jfSGW/13/

Comment: How to make "New" not to remove when I leave "a" DIV and enter mouse (Hover) on "New" DIV.

Answer (score 1):

you need to position the element on top with css: `position:absolute;`

```
#New
{
 height:40px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:red;
 position:absolute;
}
```

to have it stay there you need to remove the code `$('#New').remove();` from the 'hover out' callback.

Answer (score 1):

Use `position:absolute`

http://jsfiddle.net/jfSGW/9/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the position and a z-index above 0 (for it to display over the rest of the content) of the popup div.